# SQL Server, Merging 2 Rows into 1 and limit row grouping

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, grouping

I am currently making a SQL Query to access data in a table called "Alarms". This table is set up as in the Following Format:

`AlarmNumber |  Time | AlarmState
-------------|-------|-----------
    1046     | 10:30 |    0
    1045     | 10:25 |    1
    1044     | 10:24 |    0 
    1046     | 10:24 |    1
    1046     | 10:23 |    0
    1046     | 10:22 |    1`

What I would like to achieve is to sort the alarms Into the Following Format
The Goal is to display the Alarm Start Time, Alarm Stop Time and Alarm Active Time (Alarm End Time - Alarm Start Time)

`AlarmNumber |  AlarmStartTime | AlarmEndTime | AlarmActiveTime 
-------------|-----------------|--------------|----------------
    1046     |      10:24      |     10:30    |     00:02
    1045     |      10:24      |       -      | 10:24 + Current Time
    1044     | Shift Start Time|     10:30    |10:30 - Shift Start Time
    1046     |      10:22      |     10:23    |     00:01`

My current code is the following (Note: _Global_Vars is a table with Timezones):

```
SELECT 
    TODATETIMEOFFSET([ALARM_START_TIME],0) AT TIME ZONE (SELECT g.LocalTimeZone FROM _Global_Vars as g) AS [ALARM_START_TIME],
    TODATETIMEOFFSET(ALARM_FINISH_TIME,0) AT TIME ZONE (SELECT g.LocalTimeZone FROM _Global_Vars as g) AS [ALARM_FINISH_TIME],
    DATEDIFF(SS, [ALARM_START_TIME], [ALARM_FINISH_TIME]),
    sub.AlarmNumber
FROM
(
    SELECT 
            (a.[Time]) AS AlarmTime,
            (a.[AlarmNumber]+1) as AlarmNumber,
            (CASE WHEN a.[AlarmState] = 1 THEN a.[Time] END) [ALARM_START_TIME],
            (CASE WHEN a.[AlarmState] = 0 THEN a.[Time] END) [ALARM_FINISH_TIME]
    FROM [Alarms] as a
    WHERE (a.[Time] > DATEADD(mi, - 60.0 * 12, GETUTCDATE()))
)`
```

The issue at the moment is that if I use `MAX` in front of the `CASE` and `GROUP BY AlarmNumber`, it combines all of the values for AlarmNumber into a single row where I would like it to have multiple instances of Alarmnumber if the Alarm occurs multiple times

I am a novice regarding writing SQL Queries so any help would be great.

Comment: you did not explain the `alarmstate`

Comment: `Alarmstate` column in the original Alarm table contains a 1 or 0 depending if the alarm is active or not. I was using this to separate the times for each `alarmnumber` into `AlarmStartTime` and `AlarmEndTime`

Answer (score 0):

I will post just part of the solution (containing just first three colmns) since you not clearly specified the goal content for the last column.

```
SELECT t.alarmNumber,
   isnull(MAX(CASE WHEN t.alarmstate = 1 THEN CAST(t.[time] as varchar(20)) END), 'Shift Start Time') AlarmStartTime,
   isnull(MAX(CASE WHEN t.alarmstate = 0 THEN CAST(t.[time] as varchar(20)) END), 'Current Time') AlarmEndTime   
FROM
(
   SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by alarmnumber, alarmstate order by [time]) al_group
   FROM Alarms
) t
GROUP BY t.alarmNumber, t.al_group
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e9b851dd1fe4337c34bede443e085759)